# Making a frame visible is possible but making invisible is not

Tags: lua, roblox

```
      script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
if script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible == true then
    script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible = false
end
if script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible == false then
    script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible = true
end
end)
```

I am very new to coding (have started practically yesterday ) and ive decided to start with lua in roblox studio. The program here is working i can assure you (some things in code may not be in proper place since im having a bit trouble writing code on this site) but the code works. I have tried to make it seperatly for 2 buttons then I tried this and nothing seems to work. I am starting to think it is caused by the program itself and not the code since I can make other things invisible with that code. I've placed those 2 codes for visibility and invisibility in 1 thing since I've been told that events caused by the code happen at same time so some of them may not work.

Answer (score 2):

Assume `Visible` is true. The first condition will be true and `Visible` will be set to false. Then, in the next condition `Visible` is false and the condition is therefore true, again. And it sets `Visible` back to true.

Now, in order to fix it you want to execute the second condition only if the first failed. Take a look at `elseif` https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html.

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible == true then
        script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible = false
    elseif script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible == false then
        script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible = true
    end
end)
```

This code is still quite bulky and can be improved:

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible = not script.Parent.Parent.Frame.Visible
end)
```

Now you assign true to `Visible` if `Visible` does not evaluate to true. It basically toggles the boolean.